# Multiple assignment in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I can declare and initialize `a` and `b` like this

```
var (a, b) = Pair(1, 2)
```

But I can't reassign them like this

```
(a, b) = Pair(3, 4)
```

How come this isn't possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think there's any particular reason why destructuring can't be used when reassigning beyond "they haven't implemented it yet".

Comment: There is a link to a (5 year old) issue on the linked question, which confirms that. Requested, but not implemented.

Comment: @Adam There's quite a few issues like that—with a decent number of votes—that they just don't get around to implementing...

Comment: It would have been a nice feature and a point for consistency ;p

Answer (score -1):

that because `(a, b)` is 2 separate variables, that you initialize by `componnetN()` function. 
you can use a and b as different variables. If you vant have pair you have to write it like this `var a = Pair(2, 1)` or can use var `a = 1 to 2`

read here for more ingormation 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html

Answer (score -2):

That's because in Kotlin `(a, b, c, ...)` is not a groupping operator but a destructuring **declaration**﻿ and hence it only works for **declaring** variables, not for **reassigning**.

Comment: I think they could make a destructing assignment though.